# Очистить строку с паролем

Tags: c++, строки, безопасность, password-hash

Смысл в следующем:

1. Есть временный буфер, обычный string, в него попадает пароль.
2. Мне нужно очистить все следы этого пароля, чтобы особо одаренные не смогли найти его через дизассемблер например.

Например:

```
int main() 
{ 
    std::string str = { "Hello World!" };

    printf_s("%s\n%#x", str.c_str(), &str);

    while (true) 
    { 
        Sleep(1);
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Открываем всем известный дизассемблер(если его можно так назвать) и открываем наш процесс и делаем поиск по строке "Hello World!", находим следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее первое что мне пришло в голову, использовать функцию SecureZeroMemory.

Пробуем:

```
int main() 
{ 
    std::string str = { "Hello World!" };

    printf_s("%s\n%#x", str.c_str(), &str);

    SecureZeroMemory(&str, str.capacity());

    while (true) 
    { 
        Sleep(1);
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Повторяем манипуляции с дизассемблером, вот что он находит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже лучше, осталось "2 нахождения" + один из этих адресов как я полагаю вызов printf_s, а вот второй базовый не затерся. Далее я использовал алгоритм `fill`, результат тот же.

В конечном итоге я хочу уничтожить все следы пароля, чтобы любители реверса кода не смогли нечего найти. Пожалуйста предложите варианты.

Comment: То есть вы хотите и чтоб он был прямо в код вшит, и чтоб его никто найти не мог?...

Comment: @Harry - Да нет же, в локальную переменную попадет пароль, затем я его отправлю на сервер - далее содержимое локальной переменной должно быть уничтожено на стороне приложения клиента.

Comment: Ну так затирайте сам буфер, где он хранится. Вы же решили затереть место, где хранится `string`, а используемый ею буфер, вообще говоря, далеко не там... например, пройдитесь по всей длине строки `str`, затирая ее символы пробелами. то, что сделали вы, вообще говоря, должно привести к сбою программы в конечном итоге...

Comment: @Harry - как нужно это сделать правильно? Я ж для этого и задал вопрос чтобы мне подсказали мои ошибки-)

Comment: `SecureZeroMemory(str.c_str(), str.length());`?

Comment: @Qwertiy - нет, так затирается не все содержимое строки, подходит именно метод capacity()

Comment: @Qwertiy Формально запрещено - это константный указатель.

Comment: @Duracell, вполне всё.

Comment: @Harry, разве? о_О В любом случае лучше, чем затирать по адресу объекта.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну, с этим не поспоришь :)

Comment: Пустые хлопоты. Можно [подключиться отладчиком](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3s68z0b3.aspx) к уже работающему процессу, установить точку останова сразу после чтения пароля и посмотреть нужную память. Не знаю, как в винде, а в \*nix  этот процесс можно постараться даже автоматизировать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как я не совсем корректно задал вопрос - то отвечу сам на него. Чтобы удалить строковый литерал, нужно сделать поиск по строке в модуле приложения, найти статический базовый адрес который содержит строковый литерал, изменить атрибуты памяти, чтобы можно было перезаписать память, а затем обнулить нужный размер байт.

Comment: Вопрос один - зачем? :) Если эта строка есть просто в файле. И если уж кто-то с дизассемблером дорвется, то он что, будет молча ждать, пока строка не затрется, а только потом начинать работать? :)

Comment: @Harry - ну почему же есть обфускаторы, крипторы и т.д.

Comment: А это и есть то, что я говорил - "шифруйте". Глобально - честно скажу, сомнительной мне кажется идея, что приличный кракер, имея в руках программу, не найдет этот самый пароль...

Comment: @Harry - есть у меня одна идея, нужно сказать спасибо тебе - натолкнул на мысль о шифровании...

Answer (score 2):

Один из адресов - это инициализирующий строковый литерал `"Hello World!"`, Второй - буфер строки `str`.

Вообще говоря, вам надо затереть буфер строки, а вы зануляете кусок памяти, в котором хранится служебная информация объекта класса - указатель на тот же буфер. И еще, при длинной строке - кучу других переменных, например, содержимое стека или еще что...
То, что вы делаете, в обязательном порядке потом выйдет боком.

Вам надо перезаписать саму строку - типа,

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) str[i] = ' ';
```

(просто не помню сейчас, можно ли по стандарту обращаться к `str.data()` для записи).

**Update** Пока что формально нельзя, до C++17. Так что затирайте посимвольно.

**Update 2** И, чтобы при оптимизации компилятор не увидел, что строка не используется, и не выкинул результат, надо как-то с ней поработать.

**Update 3** Я этого не говорил :), но поскольку строки хранятся вроде бы во всех реализациях одним куском в памяти, то можно сыграть так:

```
SecureZeroMemory(&str[0], str.length());
```

только вот результат формально **не гарантирован** - надо проверять на конкретном компиляторе.

**Update 4** Как мне подсказали, результат гарантирован :)

Comment: и что-нибудь ещё сделать с этой строкой, чтобы оптимизация не выкинула.

Comment: @pavel Да, конечно, вы правы.

Comment: @Harry - Я пробовал затерать, это что мне пришло в голову в первых мыслях  for (auto it : str) {

  it = ' ';
 } - результат аналогичен SecureZeroMemory

Comment: @Duracell А получается совсем не то: вы в своем цикле получите `it` - просто `char`, а не ссылка на символ в строке, и затираете вы эту локальную переменную цикла, только и всего... **А не саму строку!**

Comment: @Harry - -) А как мне затереть саму - то эту строку?

Comment: @Duracell Я же в ответе написал, как - через `str[i]`.

Comment: @Harry - так я ж написал что не работает-), остается один статический базовый адрес(зеленый который) Могу скриншот с кодом показать и со скрином дизассемблера

Comment: Не помню, а `for (auto &it` можно? Но в любом случае, компилятор это имеет право выкинуть, так что я за `SecureZeroMemory` даже если оно не совсем по стандарту. Ну и оригинальный буфер затереть вряд ли удастся, если он в константной памяти.

Comment: @Duracell Ну так все верно - у вас остается СТРОКОВЫЙ ЛИТЕРАЛ, которым вы инициализировали строку `str`. Я же вас сразу спрашивал - вы хотите и чтоб в коде строка была, и чтоб ее никто найти не мог? Вы сказали - нет, только локальную переменную вычистить. Локальную вы чистите, а про строковый литерал я вам ничего не говорил. Он вообще в r/o памяти может сидеть! Шифруйте тогда, или еще что...

Comment: @Qwertiy Мне кажется, я понял - вы заблуждаетесь, если считаете, что ваш строковый литерал сразу оказывается в `str` - нет, он хранится в памяти, а в строку `str` попадает уже при выполнении, когда вызывается конструктор `str`...

Comment: @Harry - получается я не правильно понял тогда, да мне нужно уничтожить и строковый литерал, который статической памяти, это возможно сделать?

Comment: @Harry, нет, я не заблуждаюсь. Я понимаю, что там два места. Я же упоминал "оригинальный буфер затереть вряд ли удастся, если он в константной памяти" - это как раз про "строковый литерал ... вообще в r/o памяти может сидеть".

Comment: @Qwertiy Ой, простите! Я не то имя ввел, это не вам, это я Duracell писал, но так как одной ногой уже стоял за порогом :), вот такая ерунда вышла. Еще раз извините!

Comment: Результат гарантирован стандартом, можете убрать предупреждение. @Duracell, литерал хранится в бинарном файле, его нельзя затереть, если только бинарник перезаписывать, но Вам это не нужно.

Comment: @ixSci И `&s[0]` гарантированно указатель на первый символ? Не какой-нибудь прокси?..

Comment: Да, никаких прокси.

Comment: @ixSci, а почему `&s[0]` можно, а `s.c_str()` нельзя?

Comment: @Qwertiy, что нельзя? Модифицировать? Потому что возвращает `const char*`

Comment: @ixSci, но ведь возвращает то же самое.

Comment: @Qwertiy, то же самое, но модифицировать нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы вам не хранить пароль в зашифрованном виде? Для использования вы его расшифровываете, а потом сразу удаляете. Можно найти такой метод расшифровки, который будет делать это по частям, т.е. в каждую единицу времени у вас будет только одна часть пароля расшифрована.

Не знаю конечно, какую программу вы пишите. Но в открытом виде пароли редко хранятся. Обычно хранится хеш от пароля. Например MD5. И когда пользователь вводит пароль, то от него тоже считается хеш и сравниваются хеши, а не пароли.

Comment: Нет мне нужно его сразу удалить